# angular- disable context menu popping up when user double tap

Tags: angular, nativescript

I'm trying to disable cut, copy, paste and select all actions from a NativeScript + Angular mobile app (iOS and Android platform)

```
<TextField class="m-5 input input-border" disableCutCopyPaste> </TextField>
```

So I created a directive which works fine on Stock Android OS devices but on Custom Android OS devices, 
users can do cut, copy, paste action by double tapping on the text entered on the textfield

In order to disable double tap, I added the following line of code

```
textField.nativeView.setOnTouchListener(false);
```

in the directive I created (given below)

```
import { Directive, OnInit, OnDestroy, ElementRef, Renderer2 } from "@angular/core";
import { isIOS } from "tns-core-modules/platform";
import { layout } from "tns-core-modules/utils/utils";
import { EventData } from "tns-core-modules/data/observable";
import { TextField } from "tns-core-modules/ui/text-field";

declare var UITextField, CGRectMake;

if (isIOS) {
    UITextField.prototype._originalCanPerformActionWithSender = UITextField.prototype.canPerformActionWithSender;
    UITextField.prototype.canPerformActionWithSender = function (action, sender) {
        if (this.disableMenu) {
            return false;
        }
        return UITextField.prototype._originalCanPerformActionWithSender.call(this, action, sender)
    };
}

@Directive({
    selector: "[disableCutCopyPaste]"
})
export class DisableCutCopyPasteDirective implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

    listener: () => void;

    constructor(private renderer: Renderer2, private el: ElementRef) {

    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.listener = this.renderer.listen(this.el.nativeElement, TextField.loadedEvent, (event: EventData) => {
            const textField = <TextField>event.object;
            if (isIOS) {
                Object.defineProperty(textField.nativeView, "disableMenu", {
                    get: function () {
                        return true;
                    }
                });
            } else {
                textField.nativeView.setLongClickable(false);
                textField.nativeView.setOnTouchListener(false);
            }
        });
    }

    ngOnDestroy() {
        this.removeListener();
    }

    private removeListener() {
        if (this.listener) {
            this.listener();
            this.listener = null;
        }
    }
}
```

It's not working and I'm getting the following error

```
System.err: Error: Cannot convert boolean to Landroid/view/View$OnTouchListener; at index 0
```

I'm pretty new to NativeSCript with Angular. So any help would be appreciated.

[Playground link](https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-ng&id=0fMUcK&v=2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer the official android docs when you use native apis, `setOnTouchListener(...)` expects an instance of [View.OnTouchListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnTouchListener) interface.

```
textField.nativeView.setOnTouchListener(new android.view.View.OnTouchListener({
                onTouch: function (view, event) {
                    if (event.getAction() == android.view.MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                        view.requestFocus();
                        utils.ad.showSoftInput(view);
                    }
                    return true;
                }
            }));
```

[Updated Playground](https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-ng&id=0fMUcK&v=3)

Comment: What about iOS platform? @Manoj

Comment: The question and issue is specific to Android, did you even test it in iOS?

Comment: This works fine on Android but iOS app crashes. TypeError: Attempting to change the getter of an unconfigurable property @Manoj

Comment: This was meant for Android, not for iOS. We are using Android native apis here. You must do a platform check before running this code.

Comment: Platform check is already there. Error is getting thrown at this line- Object.defineProperty(textField.nativeView, "disableMenu", { @Manoj

Comment: Sorry its not from the original question, it seems to be a different problem. I would suggest you to create a new post with all details including error logs.

Comment: Here's the new question link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64892167/nativescript-ios-app-crashes-attempting-to-change-the-getter-of-an-unconfigura

Comment: check the link.. I have posted a new question

Answer (score 0):

setOnTouchListener() require OnTouchListener() as argument. You should try with setOnTouchListener(null) or create a OnTouchListener() that do nothing.