# nativescript ios app crashes - attempting to change the getter of an unconfigurable property

Tags: nativescript, angular2-nativescript, nativescript-angular

I created a directive to disable the context menu on android and ios app in Nativescript.

```
import { Directive, OnInit, OnDestroy, ElementRef, Renderer2 } from "@angular/core";

import { isIOS } from "tns-core-modules/platform";
import * as utils from "tns-core-modules/utils/utils";
import { EventData } from "tns-core-modules/data/observable";
import { TextField } from "tns-core-modules/ui/text-field";

declare var UITextField, CGRectMake, android;

if (isIOS) {
    UITextField.prototype._originalCanPerformActionWithSender = UITextField.prototype.canPerformActionWithSender;
    UITextField.prototype.canPerformActionWithSender = function (action, sender) {
        if (this.disableMenu) {
            return false;
        }
        return UITextField.prototype._originalCanPerformActionWithSender.call(this, action, sender)
    };
}

@Directive({
    selector: "[disableCutCopyPaste]"
})
export class DisableCutCopyPasteDirective implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

    listener: () => void;

    constructor(private renderer: Renderer2, private el: ElementRef) {

    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.listener = this.renderer.listen(this.el.nativeElement, TextField.loadedEvent, (event: EventData) => {
            const textField = <TextField>event.object;
            if (isIOS) {
                Object.defineProperty(textField.nativeView, "disableMenu", {
                    get: function () {
                        return true;
                    }
                });
            } else {
                textField.nativeView.setLongClickable(false);
                textField.nativeView.setOnTouchListener(new android.view.View.OnTouchListener({
                    onTouch: function (view, event) {
                        if (event.getAction() == android.view.MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                            view.requestFocus();
                            utils.ad.showSoftInput(view);
                        }
                        return true;
                    }
                }));
            }
        });
    }

    ngOnDestroy() {
        this.removeListener();
    }

    private removeListener() {
        if (this.listener) {
            this.listener();
            this.listener = null;
        }
    }
}
```

This code is working fine on Android devices but the iOS app is crashing and I'm getting the following error

```
TypeError: Attempting to change the getter of an unconfigurable property
```

at this line

```
Object.defineProperty(textField.nativeView, "disableMenu", {
```

Can anyone tell me what's causing this issue?

My package.json

```
{
    "nativescript": {
      "id": "com.abcde.app",
      "tns-android": {
        "version": "6.1.1"
      },
      "tns-ios": {
        "version": "6.5.3"
      }
    },
    "description": "NativeScript Application",
    "license": "SEE LICENSE IN <your-license-filename>",
    "repository": "<fill-your-repository-here>",
    "dependencies": {
      "@angular/animations": "~8.2.9",
      "@angular/common": "~8.2.9",
      "@angular/compiler": "~8.2.9",
      "@angular/core": "~8.2.9",
      "@angular/forms": "~8.2.9",
      "@angular/http": "8.0.0-beta.10",
      "@angular/platform-browser": "~8.2.9",
      "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~8.2.9",
      "@angular/router": "~8.2.9",
      "@nstudio/nativescript-checkbox": "^1.0.0",
      "@nstudio/nativescript-loading-indicator": "^1.0.0",
      "nativescript-angular": "^8.2.1",
      "nativescript-carousel": "^6.1.1",
      "nativescript-checkbox": "^3.0.3",
      "nativescript-drop-down": "^5.0.4",
      "nativescript-exit": "^1.0.1",
      "nativescript-floatingactionbutton": "^5.1.0",
      "nativescript-iqkeyboardmanager": "^1.5.1",
      "nativescript-modal-datetimepicker": "^1.2.3",
      "nativescript-plugin-firebase": "^10.0.1",
      "nativescript-root-detection": "^1.0.0",
      "nativescript-theme-core": "~1.0.4",
      "nativescript-ui-listview": "7.1.0",
      "reflect-metadata": "~0.1.13",
      "rxjs": "^6.5.3",
      "rxjs-compat": "^6.5.3",
      "simple-crypto-js": "^2.2.0",
      "tns-core-modules": "^6.5.21",
      "tns-platform-declarations": "^6.5.15",
      "zone.js": "0.9.1"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
      "@angular/compiler-cli": "8.2.9",
      "@nativescript/schematics": "~0.7.2",
      "@ngtools/webpack": "8.3.8",
      "nativescript-dev-webpack": "^1.3.0",
      "tns-android": "6.1.1",
      "typescript": "~3.5.3"
    },
    "gitHead": "9b65dfgdgdfgdgdgdfgdfd818a8205e",
    "readme": "NativeScript Application"
  }
```

[Playground Link](https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-ng&id=0fMUcK&v=3)

Comment: @Manoj ios app crashes in simulator

Comment: I just run it in my iphone 7 with ios 12. There is no error at all